# OpenCV fails to match template with image(matchTemplate)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, matchtemplate

So I have an image

[image]

and a template

[image: template]

and I want to find the template image inside the image but my code doesn't find anything. I tried down sizing but still no detection. Please help me with the example:

```
import cv2
import imutils
import glob, os
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("mainimage.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h, w = gray.shape[:2]
for file in glob.glob("template.png"):
    template = cv2.imread(file)
    template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None
    (tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
    cv2.imshow("Template", template)

    for scale in np.linspace(1, 0.2, 20)[::-1]:
        resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
        r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break
        edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
            found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    (_, maxLoc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: It could be that your template is too large (it is large in the files you loaded). For template matching, the size and rotation of the template must be very close to what is in your image. [Keypoint matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html) is good for when your template may have different sizes and rotations.

Comment: i tried keypoint matching but i got few problems,first i need to have a x,y of the detected object that is not possible to get in keypoint matching  and in lots of cases it has lots of wrong detection.@bfris

Comment: @AliSH look at answer of bfris. I don't know how you got the impression that keypoint matching is not good to locate (x,y) of template. Look at code provided by bfris. The code shows how to get location of template in image.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is mostly good. In your posted code, you were scaling the wrong way. You were shrinking the mainimage instead of growing it. Also, you need to do Canny on both template and image.

In your posted image, the template was larger (160x160) than the region in mainimage( 88x88). If you scale mainimage, then the scale factor should be 1.818. It would probably be much faster to scale the template.

```
import cv2
# import imutils
import glob, os
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread("mainimage.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h, w = gray.shape[:2]
for file in glob.glob("template.png"):
    template = cv2.imread(file)
    template = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    found = None
    (tH, tW) = template.shape[:2]
    # cv2.imshow("Template", template)

    tEdged = cv2.Canny(template, 50, 200)

    for scale in np.linspace(1, 2, 20):
        # resized = imutils.resize(gray, width=int(gray.shape[1] * scale))
        resized = cv2.resize(gray, dsize = (0,0), fx = scale, fy = scale)

        r = gray.shape[1] / float(resized.shape[1])

        if resized.shape[0] < tH or resized.shape[1] < tW:
            break
        edged = cv2.Canny(resized, 50, 200)
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(edged, tEdged, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
        (_, maxVal, _, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)

        if found is None or maxVal > found[0]:
            found = (maxVal, maxLoc, r)

    (_, maxLoc, r) = found
    (startX, startY) = (int(maxLoc[0] * r), int(maxLoc[1] * r))
    (endX, endY) = (int((maxLoc[0] + tW) * r), int((maxLoc[1] + tH) * r))
    cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', image)
    # ~ cv2.waitKey(0)
```

On my computer, this code takes 6 seconds to run.

### Keypoint matching + Homography

As an alternative, keypoint matching + homography is insensitive to scale. In the following code dst holds points containing the bounding box of the found template. For me, this following code executes in 0.06 seconds:

```
import cv2
# import imutils
import glob, os
import numpy as np
import time

image = cv2.imread("mainimage.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
h, w = gray.shape[:2]

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 3

start_time = time.time()

for file in glob.glob("template.png"):
    template = cv2.imread(file, 0)

    patchSize = 16

    orb = cv2.ORB_create(edgeThreshold = patchSize, 
                            patchSize = patchSize)
    kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(template, None)
    kp2, des2 = orb.detectAndCompute(gray, None)

    FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
    index_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
               table_number = 6,
               key_size = 12,    
               multi_probe_level = 1)
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []

    for pair in matches:
        if len(pair) == 2:
            if pair[0].distance < 0.7*pair[1].distance:
                good.append(pair[0])

    print('len(good) ', len(good))
    print('match %03d, min_match %03d, kp %03d' % (len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT, len(kp1)))
    if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,5.0)
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
        h,w = template.shape
        pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

        # dst contains points of bounding box of template in image. 
        # draw a close polyline around the found template:
        image = cv2.polylines(image,[np.int32(dst)], 
                              isClosed = True,
                              color = (0,255,0),
                              thickness = 3, 
                              linetype = cv2.LINE_AA)                    
    else:
        print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
        matchesMask = None

    draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
               singlePointColor = None,
               matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
               flags = 2)

    if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        output2 = cv2.drawMatches(template,kp1,gray,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)

    print('elapsed time ', time.time()-start_time)
    # cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    cv2.imwrite('output_homography.jpg', image)
    cv2.imwrite('output2.jpg', output2)
```

output2 from cv2.drawMatches function
[image]

One of the important parameters for keypoint detection is the patchSize. In the code, we use `patchSize = 16` for both image and template. As you make patchSize smaller, you'll get more keypoints. The smallest you can go is 2. But as you get too small, you start to get bad matches. I'm not sure how to find the sweet spot.

Comment: Because OP argued keypoint matching is not good to find location of template, I want to add that in your code, dst is the template location inside image. Please, mention this in your answer

Comment: @KadiSoheib, thanks for feedback. I updated answer and code sample to contain more explanation.

Comment: @bfris wow your code works great.but i want to say three things.1:there are some other logos in the mainimage.21 in total,.the keypoint matching doesnt work for other 20 images.is doesnt find any matching keypoint at all..that template is the only one that works with keypoint matching.if i provide other logos.can you help me with the keypoint matching?2:in cv2.polylines() i get error `TypeError: 'linetype' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`(opencv3,python3).3:anyway to improve template matching speed?also,can i give you more reputation for helping instead of simply voting up?

Comment: @AliSH I've updated the answer to have more discussion of the patchSize parameter. When I try to do keypoint matching from your sample image, I have some difficulty, too. The sample image is JPG and has lots of compression artifacts that affect the process. It could be that if you had a clean PNG screen cap, you'd get better results. Also in the OP, your template was a clean PNG and free of compression artifacts.